# @autowired need to add something to xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, autowired

I'm new to Spring. I read something about `@Autowired`. In the document, it seems when I use `@Autowired`, I have to modify the XML file, such as applicationContext.xml.

However, I read the code, and I just saw `@Autowired` in Java code, but I didn't see XML file at all. And it works well. How to use `@Autowired`, do I still need xml, if needed, how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Spring application can be configured using java. In that case you dont need application.xml.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

@Autowired
Environment env;


@Bean
public MyBean myBean(){
    return new MyBean()
}
```

}

Here @Configuration bean enables the @autowired. Following is another good example on using autowiring

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! i'll read it. If any question, i will follow up :)